# How to get response headers from RxJS's ajax?

Tags: ajax, rxjs, redux-observable

I am creating new frontend for an interview system. Some its API endpoints is updated, so getting pagination info is not a problem, but old ones still have pagination data inside response headers.

P.S. we are using react, redux and redux-observable

RxJS has the following call:

```
ajax({ ...params }).pipe(
    map(response => { 
        // here I need to somehow get headers from ajax response
    }),
    catchError(errorResponse => {
        // return error
    })
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been looking for the same answer, looks like there is a way (See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-k2ggm2?file=index.ts):

```
ajax({ ...params }).pipe(
    map(response => { 
        // here I need to somehow get headers from ajax response
        console.log(response.xhr.getAllResponseHeaders())
        console.log(response.xhr.getResponseHeader('pragma'))
    }),
    catchError(errorResponse => {
        // return error
    })
)
```

Comment: The downside is that we may need to parse it...in the age of axios, fetch and so on...it seems a little bit strange

Comment: Just have found out, that there is a fromFetch in rxjs, may be there headers can be accessed in an easier manner